# Py to exe, not found module

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Сделал проект в PyQt5. Где main.py основная программа, Scrap.py - файл с описанием GUI PyQt5. Scrapping мой пользовательский модуль, которые используется в main.py, текстовый файл используются в main.py.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался конвертировать проект с помощью pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытался по другому:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=dadata main.py
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=dadata --hidden-import=dadata.find_party main.py
```

Никак не получается. Мои импорты:

```
main.py:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Scrapping import *
from Scrap import Ui_Parser
import pyperclip
import sys

Scrap.py:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

Scrapping/Scrap.py:
from dadata.find_party import DadataFindPartyClient
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
from datetime import *
```

Подскажите, как можно собрать этот проект в exe файл?

Answer (score 2):

При вызове pyinstaller у вас в том же каталоге должен создаться spec файл. В нём отражается файловая структура из которой он пытался собрать exe. Посмотрите глазами, каких ваших файлов не хватает и допишите в словарь Analysis. После чего можно попробовать запустить команду pyinstaller main.spec